# Is Sandhyavandanam different for each vedic line/shakha brahmin?

Tags: vedas, rituals, sandhyavandanam

Is sandhyavandanam ritual different for each vedic line? Or is it same for all brahmins no matter what veda they belong to?

Comment: they are slightly different for each veda. the major parts - achamana, pranayama, sankalpa, tyaga, prokshana, prashana, arghya, tarpana, japa, upasthana, dik-vandana - will be there for all vedas, but the mantras, their pronunciation, their mudras etc. are different.

Comment: @ram: Can you please guide me to some text material/UTube video for **good** source to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

However same the conceptual aspects of Sandhya Vandana for all the veda, they are slightly different for different Vedic lines and also even within the same Vedas like Shukla and Krishna Yajur vedas..

Between Rig + Yajur and Sama vedas the mantras for the following are different,

Praasanam- drinking a small drop of water while uttering Mantra to purify internally, and

Prayaschitta Arghyam - Offering small quantity of water (pouring it down with Hand) as a remedy for doing the Sandhyavandanam out of prescribed time.

Morning Praashna for Sama Veda:

*Ahascha maa adithyascha punathu swaha*

Morning Praashna for Rig and Yajur Veda:

*Sooryashcha ma manyushcha manyu patayashcha manyukRutebhya paapebhyo rakshantam yad raatryaa paapa maa karsham manasaa vaachaa hastabhyam padbhyaam udareNa shishna raatreeh tadaa valumbatu yad kincha duritam mayi idam aham mama amRuta yonou soorya jyotishee juhomi svaahaa*

Afternoon Praashna: Pretty much the Same for all vedas..

*Aapa punanthu prithweem, prithwee pootha punathu maam
Punanthu brahmanaspathir brahma pootha punathu maam
Yad uchishta mabhojyam yadhwa ducharitham mama
Sarvam punanthu mamopa asatham cha prathigraham swaha*

Evening  Praashna:

Rig + Yajur:
*Agnishcha ma manyushcha manyu patayashcha manyu kRutebhya paapebhyo rakshantam yadahna paapama karsham manasaa vaachaa hastabhyam paadabhyam udareNa shishna ahastada valumbatu 
yad kinchid duritam mayi idamaham maam amRuta yonau satye jyotishee juhomi swaahaa*

Sama Veda:
*Rathrischa ma varunascha punathu swaha.*

Rig + yajur also differ with Sama Veda for Punar Marjana(Literally: Another Purification). This is to cleanse again, say if you utter the above lines in Anger! Manyu, is the God responsible for our Anger. Some Pandits told me Manyu is a brother of Saturn or Shaneeshwar. Strangely, Sama Veda does not propitiate Manyu in Praashnam. They are supposed to let Anger be I guess :-)

Once you cleanse yourself, you do Arghya which is the Single most important part of Sandhyavandhana - Water offering while chanting Gaayatri mantra that is suppose to Help Sun fight off crores of Evil demonic spirits that attack him Morning and Evening. They are called  Mandeyha demonic Asuras ~300 million. Pop quiz: Why not afternoon?
Accordingly, the Arghya offerings is more in the Morning and Evening...

You might ask, how an offering of water by some person on Earth going to help Sun.

Well, Duh! 
How did you miss to see that as a Homomorphically Encrypted action that is quantum entangled with Sun :-)?

Brahma, initiated this ritual especially for Brahmin men to help Sun.That's why Brahmins are suppose to help Earth as a whole by doing Sandhyavandhanam...

Invoke Gayatri devi and Chant Gayatri (to replenish your power to help Sun) and then finally Ask her to return to her Abode - Upasthanam.

Gaayatri Upasthanam - To let Gaayatri devi return to her original abode from whence she descended. The Upasthana Mantras are different as well for different Vedas probably to indicate that She takes a different path to reach you or also could be Different Rishis
introduced different Mantras...

Here are some links...

https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/2015/08/21/rig-veda-sandhya-vandhana-mantras-english/
https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/sama-veda-sandhyavandana-text-english/
https://www.scribd.com/doc/18663569/Yajurveda-Sandhyavandanam
https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/tag/sandhyavandanam/